# Find duplicate record in csv by shell script(Ubuntu)

Tags: csv, awk

I have below csv

```
name,mobile
name1,123456
name2,98765
name1,123456
name3,98765
name1,123456
name4,344545443
```

If two record has mobile then that record will be considered as duplicate . But while printing the duplicate record first record has to ignore

So my output should be like this

```
name,mobile
name1,123456
name1,123456
name2,98765
```

So here 123456 is 3 times in my file but I only want to print it two time for me first occurrence is unique and all other occurrence is duplicate.

I have tried

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR {++A[$2]; next} A[$2]>1'  file1.csv file1.csv
```

It gives me

```
name1,123456
name2,98765
name1,123456
name3,98765
name1,123456
```

it's not ignoring the first occurrence

Please help me on this

Comment: @NicoHaase awk -F, 'NR==FNR {++A[$2]; next} A[$2]>1'  file1.csv file1.csv
This is not ignoring the first occurrence

Comment: What happened to "name3" and "name4" in your output?

Comment: @glennjackman By usiing above script I am getting below output
name1,123456
name2,98765
name1,123456
name3,98765
name1,123456

Comment: @NicoHaase I have updated my question. Please have a look and help me to get out of it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand your question, you want to output records where the 2nd field occurs at least twice, but do not output the first instance.

```
awk -F, '++seen[$2] > 1' file
```

Given your sample data, this prints

```
name1,123456
name3,98765
name1,123456
```

This is lines 4,5,6 from the input data.